# C# SslStream throws IOException on second request

Tags: c#, ssl, tcp, pop3, sslstream

Again me, yes. 5 minute of coding = 1 day trying to fix the code. Here is my code, which throws IOException (Unable to read from stream) **only on the second request**, the first works fine. The exception is thrown at `bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);` I've tried to fix this with no results.

Here is the code for request function:

```
public void SendRequest(string request)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int bytes = -1;
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder() ;

    sslStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request + "\r\n"));
    do
    {
        try
        {
            bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            message.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

    } while(!message.ToString().Contains("\n"));
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Code calling `SendRequest()` function:

```
while((request = Console.ReadLine().ToLower()) != "exit")
{
    con.SendRequest(request);
}
```

If u want full code, check it here: [GitHub Repo](http://github.com/WizzieP/MailerPrototype)

Comment: Where is `sslStream` defined?

Comment: In same class (TcpConnector) as `SendRequest()` function, and I'm connecting with it in class' constructor (it works well).

Comment: @Endy Perhaps the request is timing out?

Comment: I was debugging it man, posting here is last thing I do, I've tried too google it, fix, debug. The exception says: unable to read data from transport connection. The rest isn't in english, but it's something like: "connection has been closed by software installed on computer-host".

Comment: Sorry for not posting full exception, but I thought that description is the same for every IOException :D

Comment: Could it be that the other side just did not send anything, or did not send a newline? How did you make sure this is not the case?

Comment: I'm connecting to pop.gmail.com, it should answer smth like "-ERR xxxx" or "+OK" whatever you send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what's going on now. I'm connecting to POP3 server - after greeting message the session is in AUTHORIZATION state, when I must pass two commands: `USER` and `PASS`, if I don't pass right commands, the server closes connection (that's why I get IOException). The only 3 commands, which doesn't close the connection are propably: `USER`,`PASS`, `QUIT`. I hope this thread will help someone in the future :)